# JUnit 4 Test Method with local inner class is inconsistent across Test Cases

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, inner-classes

OK, I searched as best I could for this and couldn't find anything.  I'm a first-time asker so be gentle. :p

Within one test case I have a test method to test a given event listener method when it gets fired.

```
public class TestCaseDoingSupport {

    public TestCaseDoingSupport() {
        super();
    }
    @Test
    public void testFireEventDoingSomething() {

       class LocalDoingListener extends DoingAdapter {

                    public LocalDoingListener() {
                        super();
                    }
                    public void onStartedDoingSomething(DoingEvent event) {
                        Assert.assertEquals(DoingClass.STARTED_DOING_SOMETHING, event.getDoingStatus());
                    }
                }

                DoingListener listener = new LocalDoingListener();
                DoingSupport support = new DoingSupport(new DoingClass());
                support.addDoingListener(listener);
                support.fireStartedDoingSomething();
            }
}
```

The problem I have is this:  this *exact* pattern is used in two other test cases (in the same project) for two other event listeners and it works perfectly well, but in the test case I have issues with I get (from the test report) `java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public constructor`.

I really don't understand why this pattern works in one test case but not in another - I even tried taking the constructor out, but it made no difference.  Has anyone run into this issue and if so, how did you solve it?

Many thanks.

**EDIT:**
I tried making the constructor of the method-local class public (reflected in the code fragment posted) but the complaint in the test report the same.  At the command line, *gradle* reports:

```
com.example.testTestCaseDoingSupport$1LocalDoingListener > initializationError FAILED
    java.lang.Exception
```

Full stack trace posted below.

```
java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateZeroArgConstructor(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:147)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateConstructor(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:124)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:355)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:360)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you construct a minimal code example?

Comment: Along with the full stack trace. At this stage, I'd assuming it's complaining about the class containing the `testFireEventDoingSomething` method not having a single public constructor, but that's not immediately obvious.

Comment: @ipsi Stack trace added.  It doesn't seem to matter whether the method-local event listener's constructor has public or local scope, the complaint is the same.  This pattern should either succeed consistently or fail consistently, but it works in two other test cases, which is what I find odd.

Comment: How are you running the test?

Comment: @shmosel Just via a standard call to _gradle clean build_.  I don't define any specific test tasks.

Comment: Well it looks like you're running `LocalDoingListener` as a test class instead of `TestCaseDoingSupport`.

Comment: **@shmosel**  Do these pages update via AJAX?  I didn't see your comment before I posted the answer and you are 100% right, so many thanks for pointing me in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found it.  In my *gradle* script, I have this

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    scanForTestClasses = false
    exclude "**/*\$5*.class"
}
```

to avoid treating inner classes as test classes.  Editing this to `exclude "**/*\$*.class"` solved it for *all* inner classes.

I can't believe I didn't see this earlier...